# windows automation tool to glue various tasks together

Tags: windows, automation

on windows, are there any tools for automation? for example, to accomplish one task, I need to run build targets in multiple projects in sequence in an IDE(eg. eclipse).  I wish to have a single command/click option.  can this be done?

on linux I can use bash scripts to glue things together.

Comment: There is no definitive answer as many apps are simply not automatable. Have you googled a bit? What have you tried? Suggestions; http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-task-automation/

Comment: `Autohotkey` allows you to build a script for various tasks to be launched by hotkey.  It can press keys and click spots, start programs etc.  `Batch files` are the equivalent techniques to bash scripts though not as straight forward.  They leverage `powershell` `vbs` `jscript` and external and third party commands.  This question is more about opinion than factual code.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for Linux bash scripts is [Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714418.aspx).

One of its main purposes is task automation. It is widely used for administrative tasks like the ones you mention above. You can create functions, scripts (files suffixed by .ps1) or even standalone executable programs.

You can also try [the Script Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419) for a start!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Oddjob](http://www.rgordon.co.uk/oddjob/index.html).

There is also a class of tools that can be searched for using this keywords: "build automation tool", "continuous integration server". For example, [Precision Builder Express](http://www.be-precision.com/products/precision-builder/express/).